# 'Ionic cordova build android' gives error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm publishing the ionic app but i cant build it. When  gives this error

i try build project

```
ionic cordova build --release android
```

it gives this error

```
System cannot find the path specified
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
    cordova build android --release exited with exit code 1.
    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure to add android platform to your ionic project

```
 -ionic cordova platform add android 
 - ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

Answer (score 0):

- Did you install Android Studio.
- Did you do  `npm install cordova -g`
- Did you do `npm install ionic -g`

Also make sure you did all this:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/android

(Especially the correct SDK is essential)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have ran 
`cordova prepare android` it could be that the android platform is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Its not an ionic error.It occurs when there isn't any setting of path in system variables.You have to follow this link.
  https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-do-i-setup-the-environment-to-work-with-ionic-and-cordova/117054/7